# How to use wp_localize_script in a WordPress page other than functions.php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a contact form in a WordPress page like this:

```
$( '#contact_form' ).bootstrapValidator({
    fields: {
        // ...
    },
    submitHandler: function( formInstance ) {
        $.post( "../send-message", $("#contact_form").serialize(), function( result ) { 
            alert( pw_script_vars.State );            
        });
    }
});
```

When the form is submitted using the Ajax request it goes to another WordPress page titled `/send-message` that has PHP code to send an email, then it should return a success or failure value to the Ajax request to alert a success or failure message. I have tried using the `wp_localize_script` function in the `functions.php` file using a fixed value and it worked fine:

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'pw_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/inc/js/functions.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'pw_script', 'pw_script_vars', array( 'State' => 'success' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```

But when I tried to use the `wp_localize_script` in the `/send-message` WordPress page it failed to work. Here are the contents of the '/send-message' page :

```
<?php
    $sendSuccess = sendMessage();

    if( $sendSuccess )
        wp_localize_script( 'pw_script', 'pw_script_vars', array( 'State' => 'success' ) );
    else
        wp_localize_script( 'pw_script', 'pw_script_vars', array( 'State' => 'failure' ) );

    function sendMessage() {
        //This function will send the email then it will return true or false.
    }
?>
```

Using `wp_localize_script` in the `/send-message` causes an undefined variable `pw_script_vars` in the JavaScript file.

How can I use `wp_localize_script` in a WordPress page other than `functions.php`?

Comment: Is `send-message` a normal WP page ? What does `sendMessage()` function contains? How are you defining success or failure on `send-message` page to pass it back to AJAX handler?

Comment: [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) is a shorthand form `$.ajax` post , for which the third parameter is the success callback

Comment: @bravokeyl ... Yes, '/send-message' is a normal WordPress page. sendMessage() function has php code to send an email. I didn't implement it yet but it'd return success if the email is sent or failure if the email wasn't sent. It is just a PHP boolean or String variable! .. The thread you have shared is a different example; he's using a php page(sendmessage.php) and not a WordPress page.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `wp_localize_script` in page template. You have to use it in `functions.php` or your custom plugin, after you register your script, which is usually in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: You can hook into 'enqueue_scripts' anytime you want, also in plugins or in a custom page template. This answer is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to move your wp_localize_script anywhere else. Your problem lies within the fact that you try to use AJAX outside of WordPress. Let me refer to an earlier answer of me showing a simple version of how to use AJAX in WordPress [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/229576/81939)